# Hovering over an image to show a text box is not working (html, css)

Tags: html, css, hover

When hovering over the image, a textbox should be shown. However, it is not working for me and I am completely stuck.

These are the code snippets, thank you in advance.

```css
#passinfo {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

#infotext {
  background-color: #628ca0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.829);
  padding: 5px 4px 4px 4px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

#passinfo .img:hover #infotext {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h4>Password</h4>
<img src="infoicon.png" id="passinfo">
<div id="infotext">Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, and a number.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector:

```
#passinfo .img:hover #infotext
```

is looking for the element with `id="infoText"` that is a descendant of an element with a *class* of `img`, that is hovered-over, that is itself a descendant of an element with `id="passinfo"`.

Your `<img>` element does not have a class of `img`, it *is* an `<img>` element and itself has the `id="passinfo"`; and `<img>` elements cannot have any child, or descendant, elements of any kind (not even pseudo-elements); so this selector will, and *can*, never apply.

Instead, you're looking for – and should use – the following:

```
#passinfo:hover + #infotext
```

Which selects the element with `id="infotext"` which is the immediately-adjacent sibling of the element with a class of `img`, that is hovered-over.

```css
#passinfo {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

#infotext {
  background-color: #628ca0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.829);
  padding: 5px 4px 4px 4px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

#passinfo:hover + #infotext {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h4>Password</h4>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" id="passinfo">
<div id="infotext">Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, and a number.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#passinfo .img:hover #infotext {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

to

```
#passinfo:hover
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: The textbox still will not appear when I hover over the image. It only appears if I change `#passinfo:hover` to `#infotext:hover` and hover over the invisible text box

Answer (score 1):

Move your #passinfo into a div wrapping the image and text, and use that to set the :hover.

```
<h4>Password</h4>
  <div id='passinfo'>
    <img src="icon.png">
    <div id="infotext">Password must be...</div>
  </div>

#passinfo:hover #infotext {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

W3Schools.com is a great resource for stuff like this if you haven't heard of it. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
#passinfo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: This may or may not be correct, however, in any case, you should add a few lines of text to explain what you are doing and why you believe it to be the correct answer.